# "~" appear as a subdirectory in my project directory

Tags: macos, filesystems

I encountered a very strange issue. Under one of my project directory, I notice there is a subdirectory "~". And the content is basically identical to my home directory. I dare not remove it as I am afraid it may screw up my entire FS. Any good advice?

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a very minor concern you could of created a **HARD** linked directory, however that is only possible on OSX in some extremely unusual circumstances (it can't be done with the basic `ln` command on OSX) it typically requires code specially written for that purpose. In order to check for that you would need to verify the iNode numbers of both locations i.e.:

```
ls -id ~
ls -id '~'
```

If you had a hard link the numbers would be the same.

---

Therefore I am tempted to say that the simplest possibility is the most likely - At some point you just copied your home directory to this location.

The easiest way to check that is just create a new file in your real home directory and see if it appears in this directory - if the new file isn't there most likely this directory is just a copy and can be deleted.

Comment: thanks for your help. My bad...it is actually a subdirectory that has the "~" as name. It is accidentally created by my shell script (to spawn a headless browser) when I use "~" in the "--user-data-dir" parameter value. 
The "~" and many files created by chrome must have confused me. 
When the ls -id command returns me different id, I took a closer look and see the difference.

so apparently google chrome commandline parameter "--user-data-dir" doesn't interpret "~" properly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's just a link to your home directory, which can be made in any other directory, even subdirs of your home:

[softlink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsjyH.png)

If this is your case, you can safety remove it:

[rm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74zcp.png)

Comment: `lrwxr-xr-x  1 davidt  staff      13 Oct 28 22:57 ~ -> /Users/davidt` is how it would look if it was a soft link - it wouldn't have the 'd' at the begining.

Comment: Actually, in my image `~/part` is the main softlink. @DavidT

Comment: is there any command to run to verify the nature of this folder? It doesn't look like symbolic link that I used to work with

Comment: As I know, it is just a directory. You can use `stat \~` to get more info about it.